# How to set logger class universally in Django App

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a logger that just adds log_line if none is provided when calling logger.debug

```
class UrlLogger(logging.Logger):
    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None):
        if extra is None:
            extra = {'log_line':' '}
        super(UrlLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra)
```

I have about 20 different modules that I need to go into and add

```
logging.setLoggerClass(UrlLogger)
```

How can I set this as default in the settings?

My settings currently look like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(pathname)s@%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)8s] [%(asctime)s] %(module)10s/%(filename)s:%(log_line)s - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'class': ['UrlLogger'],
    },
```

As you can see, I tried setting it here, but I don't think that's working because I am still getting errors.

```
Message: 'Not Found: %s'
Arguments: ('/tool_job_list/1/1fa119372de6/job/check/jexecution/report',)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 547, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'log_line'
```

This error occurs when the front end makes failed API calls (wrong uri) to the django backend.  I'm thinking that the failed api call is logging the error without using my UrlLogger (otherwise there would not be a key error unless there is an error in my Logger Class).

What am I doing wrong here?